# maximum likelihood estimation

Tags: r, regression

I am new user of R and hope you will bear with me if my question is silly. I want to estimate the following model using the maximum likelihood estimator in R.

```
y= a+b*(lnx-α)
```

Where a, b, and α are parameters to be estimated and X and Y are my data set. I tried to use the following code that I get from the web:

```
library(foreign)
maindata <- read.csv("C:/Users/NUNU/Desktop/maindata/output2.csv")
h <- subset(maindata, cropid==10)
library(likelihood)
modelfun <- function (a, b, x) { b *(x-a)}
par <- list(a = 0, b = 0)
var<-list(x = "x")
par_lo <- list(a = 0, b = 0)
par_hi <- list(a = 50, b = 50)
var$y <- "y"
var$mean <- "predicted"
var$sd <- 0.815585
var$log <- TRUE
results <- anneal(model = modelfun, par = par, var = var,
            source_data = h, par_lo = par_lo, par_hi = par_hi,
            pdf = dnorm, dep_var = "y", max_iter = 20000)
```

The result I am getting is similar although the data is different, i.e., even when I change the cropid. Similarly, the predicted value generated is for x rather than y.
I do not know what I missed or went wrong. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: There are several issues here. (1) it would be nice to have a reproducible example ( http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 ). (2) the model as you state it originally is *unidentifiable*; it's equivalent to a linear model of `y` on `ln(x)` with parameters slope=`b` and intercept `a-αb` -- that is, you're trying to estimate three parameters from what is essentially a two-parameter model. (3) As you've specified `pdf` as `dnorm`, as David Winsemius said, this is exactly a simple linear model.  Less importantly, (4) the `foreign` package is unnecessary ...

Comment: `cropid` ??? The very similar example in the `help(anneal)` page uses "x" for the dependent variable. You are aware that simulated annealing is NOT a deterministic method right? You have no basis for worrying about small differences.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if your model formula will lead to a unique solution, but in general you can find MLE with `optim` function

Here is a simple example for linear regression with optim:

```
fn <- function(beta, x, y) {
a = beta[1]
b = beta[2]

    sum( (y - (a + b * log(x)))^2 ) 
}

# generate some data for testing
x = 1:100

# a = 10, b = 3.5
y = 10 + 3.5 * log(x)

optim(c(0,0,0),fn,x=x,y=y,method="BFGS")
```

you can change the function "*fn*" to reflect your model formula e.g.

```
sum( (y - (YOUR MODEL FORMULA) )^2 )
```

**EDIT**

I am just giving a simple example of using optim in case you have a custom model formula to optimize. I did not mean using it from simple linear regression, since `lm` will be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

I was a bit surprised that iTech used optim for what is a problem that is linear in its parameters. With his data for x and y:

```
> lm(y ~ log(x) )

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ log(x))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       log(x)  
       10.0          3.5
```

For linear problems, the least squares solution is the ML solution.

Comment: I was just giving a simple example for using optim. What I understood from the question that it needs to optimize a custom function not just ordinary linear regression with log(x) transformation.

Comment: The OP probably still needs help with the `likelihood::anneal` function setup, but first he needs to offer a reproducible example.